# Flutter OAuth1.0 Fatsecret API Error: Invalid signature: oauth_signature 'ziNCxJykqOEMRV51C8MFx5LN%2Fi4%3D'

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth

I usually don't post questions here, but I've been stuck for days.
I couldn't find any answers with online research either.
I hope someone here can help me. I want to use the Fatsecret API with Flutter and am using OAuth1.0 for it. The documentation can be found at https://platform.fatsecret.com/docs/guides/authentication/oauth1.

I followed all the steps, created a signature base string, and then calculated the signature value using HMAC-SHA1. Unfortunately, I receive the following error:

```
Success: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
I/flutter (10963): <error xmlns="http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/1.0/ http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/1.0/fatsecret.xsd">
I/flutter (10963):  <code>8</code>
I/flutter (10963):  <message>Invalid signature: oauth_signature 'ziNCxJykqOEMRV51C8MFx5LN%2Fi4%3D'</message>
I/flutter (10963): </error>
```

I can't see where I'm going wrong. Perhaps someone might notice what I'm doing incorrectly.

My Flutter code:
I have checked the consumer key and consumer secret multiple times, and they are correctly implemented in the code. For security reasons, I have entered them here simply as the string "secret".

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

  String consumerKey = "secret"
  String consumerSecret = "secret";
  String url = 'https://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api';

  String oauthNonce = "";
  String signature = "";

  String getSignature() {
    // Step 1: HTTP Method
    String httpMethod = "POST";

    // Step 2: Request URL
    String encodedRequestUrl = Uri.encodeComponent(url);

    // Step 3: Normalized Parameters
    Map<String, String> params = {
      'oauth_consumer_key': consumerKey,
      'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
      'oauth_timestamp': timestamp.toString(),
      'oauth_nonce': oauthNonce,
      'oauth_version': '1.0',
      'food_id': '33691',
      'method': 'food.get.v3',
    };

    // Sort parameters and concatenate in a string
    // Sort parameters
    List<String> sortedKeys = params.keys.toList()..sort();

    // Concatenate parameters in a string
    List<String> keyValuePairList =
        sortedKeys.map((k) => '$k=${params[k]}').toList();

    // Join string with '&'
    String normalizedParameters = keyValuePairList.join('&');

    // Encode the string
    String encodedNormalizedParameters =
        Uri.encodeComponent(normalizedParameters);

    // Create the signature base string
    String signatureBaseString =
        '$httpMethod&$encodedRequestUrl&$encodedNormalizedParameters';

    // HMAC-SHA1 signature
    var key = utf8.encode(consumerSecret);
    var bytes = utf8.encode(signatureBaseString);

    var hmacSha1 = Hmac(sha1, key);
    var digest = hmacSha1.convert(bytes);

    String base64Signature = base64Encode(digest.bytes);
    String encodedBase64Signature = Uri.encodeComponent(base64Signature);
    return encodedBase64Signature;
  }

  void makeRequest() async {
    Random rand = Random();
    List<int> codeUnits = List.generate(10, (index) {
      return rand.nextInt(26) + 97;
    });
    oauthNonce = String.fromCharCodes(codeUnits);
    signature = getSignature();

    final headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization':
          'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="$consumerKey", oauth_nonce="$oauthNonce", oauth_signature="$signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="$timestamp", oauth_version="1.0"'
    };
    final body = {
      'food_id': '33691',
      'method': 'food.get.v3',
      'oauth_consumer_key': consumerKey,
      'oauth_nonce': oauthNonce,
      'oauth_signature': signature,
      'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
      'oauth_timestamp': timestamp.toString(),
      'oauth_version': '1.0',
    };

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Success: ${response.body}');
    } else {
      print('Error: ${response.body}');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    makeRequest();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```